# server push jsp

Tags: jsp, server-push

There are so many option make a server push application with reverse AJAX and DWR lib. But all they are with AJAX based application. I want build simple server push application with JSP which will push the message to client. It will be great if someone give code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP wasn't designed for server-side push. If you want that, you'll need to do it from the client with Javascript or some other technology like Flash or Silverlight.

There are a lot of frameworks out there that "hide" the client side code though. Look at [Apache Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/) for example, or [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/), [vaadin](http://vaadin.com/home), ... and many others.

Comment: I know http wasn't designed such way. But I have read somewhere there is some library available for JSP.

Comment: there are some frameworks that hide the client part - added some links. Maybe you'll find your ideal solution somewhere on this [Java Ajax Frameworks](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Java_Ajax_Frameworks) page.